# How to use $filter in angular 2? I have given the angular 1.x code and I want the similar code for angular 2

Tags: filter, angular

I have done the multi column filtering in angular 1.x and I want the similar functionality angular 2. Here I given the angular 1.x code.

```
$scope.data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, { head: $scope.HEAD, problem: $scope.PROBLEM, category: $scope.CATEGORY, subcategory: $scope.SUBCATEGORY, region: $scope.REGION });
```

and I tried it in angular 2,

```
let f = new filtering();
this.data = f.transform([this.HEAD, this.PROBLEM, this.CATEGORY, this.SUBCATEGORY, this.REGION]);
```

Comment: i want the pipe for the multi column filtering functionality

Comment: I guess I would need some more explanation what you actually try to accomplish. I don't know Angular 1.x well.

Comment: can you give us an example of `an input` and `expected output`, that would be very fruitful